# Mongodb c sharp driver document update error

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am using c# mongo db driver to insert and update a document. First i insert a record and then I try to update a specific field of record using FindOneAndUpdateAsync method. I am able to update it properly but after update I am getting a error "Required element 'Name' for property 'Name' of class SampleApp.Person is missing." I am using MongoCommunity edition 4.4.1 and mongo driver is 2.11.4.

I am attaching image of mongo compass view for your reference.[image: Compass View]

My collection structure is

```
[BsonSerializer(typeof(ImpliedImplementationInterfaceSerializer<IPerson, Person>))]
public interface IPerson
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Age { get; set; }
    string Email { get; set; }
    IAddress Address { get; set; }
    bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public IAddress Address { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}

public interface IAddress
{
    string Line1 { get; set; }
    string Line2 { get; set; }
    string Line3 { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; }
    string State { get; set; }
    string Pincode { get; set; }
}

public class Address : IAddress
{
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Pincode { get; set; }
}
```

My code to insert and update is as shown below.

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Address>();
var peopleCollection = database.GetCollection<IPerson>("People");
IPerson person = new Person()
{
    Age = 50,
    Email = "a@a.com",
    IsActive = false,
    Name = "David",
    Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString()
};
try
{
    await peopleCollection.InsertOneAsync(person);
    IAddress address = new Address()
    {
        City = "Bengaluru",
        Line1 = "Bengaluru",
        Line2 = "Bengaluru",
        Line3 = "Bengaluru",
        Pincode = "560001",
        State = "KA"
    };

    var updateDefinition = Builders<IPerson>.Update.Set(x => x.Address, address).Set(x => 
    x.IsActive, true);
    var filter = Builders<IPerson>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Email, "a@a.com");
    FindOneAndUpdateOptions<IPerson> updateOptions = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<IPerson>
    {
        IsUpsert = false,
        ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After,
        Projection = Builders<IPerson>.Projection.Include(c => c.Address)
    };
    IPerson updatedPerson = await peopleCollection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, updateDefinition, updateOptions);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       string s = ex.Message;
       Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Comment: The properties in the classes need to be public for serialization to work.

Comment: Have you tried removing the `[BsonRequired]` and see what you get as a response? The error is saying that whatever value is retrieved, it's missing the `Name` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the value pre-update, does not have the Name property at all, so when the `FindOneAndUpdateAsync` gets the data and tries to deserialize it (before updating) it fails with that error.

Two solutions for this

1. Try removing the `[BsonRequired]` so that youy avoid this error.
2. Try to update all the documents in the MongoDB instance, to have the `Name` property, before running your code.

Comment: Removing [BsonRequired] will remove this error. I am curious to know that is it mandatory to provide all required fields during update.

Comment: I think that it shouldn't be. The already existing document on MongoBD, must have all the required properties though, before you can find and update.

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers if you find them helpful.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for quick response